# Is there an XQuery IRC?

Tags: xquery, irc, marklogic

Does anyone know of an IRC channel for XQuery (or even MarkLogic)?  I can't seem to find an active one by searching the googles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of none.  I didn't think IRC was actively used much this century ...
The various mailing lists are very active and timely though.

http://x-query.com/mailman/listinfo/talk
http://developer.marklogic.com/mailman/listinfo/general

Its also useful to be considerate of peoples time ... using mailing lists lets people answer questions when they have time instead of feeling pressured to answer an "Emergency" question in realtime.

-David

Comment: Oh, IRCs are quite active for things like PHP, Ruby, various frameworks, etc.  I think they're nice for more than just emergency stuff.  Often times you get a realtime conversations going that explore "tangential" topics that you don't see as often on mailing lists.  Plus I'm against anything more coming into my inbox than I have to.